# How to sync 2 folders using NFC between two Android devices running slightly different Android OS versions

Tags: sync, 5.1-lollipop, networking, nfc, file-sharing

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 running lollipop and another jiayu s3 running Android 4.4. Both of them have NFC. I want to  sync a folder in internal storage from one phone with another using Android NFC feature. NFC enabled in both devices. So when I use ES File Explorer in the source device I do not see any option that lets me invoke NFC sharing. I may be able to share using  Bluetooth or LAN. So how is NFC invoke can it be invoked Nativity or you need 3rd party applications.

It need not be nfc... I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to sync two directories on Android devices without the need to be on a network. thank you

Comment: I don't think you really want to use NFC for the *syncing* itself (that's pretty slow even compared to Bluetooth). Maybe you rather want to use it to *initiate* the sync process? Usually, initiating an "NFC action" is done by holding two devices with NFC enabled back-to-back, then tap the screen of the "sender" to confirm the action (e.g. sharing a picture that's displayed on the screen at that moment). It's AFAIK the foreground app which has to decide on the action, though – so I'm not sure how e.g. ES would react.

Comment: Yes I could get picture sharing to work that way but when I touch the butts and use ES file explorer I hear a noise and there nothing happening on both phones then onwards. I wonder how we can synch 2 folders the fastest without having to connect to wi-fi . How about using one phone as OTA USB for another ?

Comment: I've never heard of syncing directories between Android devices initiated via NFC, sorry. While waiting for answers, maybe some results of [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+file+sync+nfc) have some clues?

Comment: It need not be nfc... I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to sync two directories on Android devices without the need to be on a network. thank you

Comment: Without any network that won't work, as they cannot connect to each other. With Bluetooth that will be slow as hell. So your best option would be WiFi Direct or using one device as Hotspot. Then you could use an automation tool like [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) on the other device with a rule like "when you see this hotspot, connect and sync". *FolderSync* would support *Tasker* in this, but you'd need some kine of [file server](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server) on the hotspot device for that. Just a raw idea.